# Android webview onPause causes application to restart

Tags: android, android-webview, onpause, application-restart

In my android application, if my application goes to background , I call mWebView.onPause() in activity onPause() callback.

I have noticed that , if the application is brought to foreground in 15-20 seconds, the application retains its state
[ onResume() callbacks comes ]
but if it is done after 2 minutes, the application restarts with call to onStart() callback.

If I comment mWebView.onPause(), then applications always resumes its state, doesn't matter how much time after.

Could someone tell why such behaviour is observed ? 
More details about my application,

All initialization, url loading is being done in onCreate().
in onResume() activity callback,

```
mWebView.onResume();
mWebView.resumeTimers();
```

in onPause() callback,

```
mWebView.pauseTimers();
 mWebView.onPause();
```

Nothing is done in onStart() and onStop() callback.

Tried launchMode = "singleInstance"
not working

If I comment mWebView.onPause(), things works fine. No restart.

```
mWebView.onResume();
mWebView.resumeTimers();

mWebView.pauseTimers();
mWebView.onPause();
```

I expect application to not restart when it comes to foreground after 2-3 minutes.